# What do these format specifiers mean?

Tags: python

```
print("%c is my %s letter and my number %d number is %.5f"%
      ("X",'favorite',1,.14))
```

I just wanna make sure that `%c=character`,`%d=digit`,`%f=float`,and `5f=0.00000`,am I right?

Comment: Note that you may pass `%c` either a single character OR an integer character code. Also note that the use of %-style formatting in new code is discouraged, and use of the `format` function or method is preferred. But I must admit that as an old C coder I'm still rather attached to %-style formatting. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Format specification can be found from [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), here are the relevant parts:

'c' - Character. Converts the integer to the corresponding unicode character before printing.
'd' - Decimal Integer. Outputs the number in base 10.
'f' - Fixed point. Displays the number as a fixed-point number. The default precision is 6.

Comment: Thank you for the web info senpai!

Comment: Consider adding a quote from that website in case in the future it becomes unavailable